Deploy the Laravel VueJs project onto the Cpanel
how are you? I hope you are doing well! I have a query regarding a project using Laravel and Vue.js. I want to deploy this project on cPanel. After running npm run build, a directory is created in my public directory. When I deploy the project, my domain URL is https://podstaging.ibexstack.com/. However, when I append /public to the URL like this: https://podstaging.ibexstack.com/public, the page is blank. It seems my app.css and app.js files in the resources folder are not being loaded.
now get me the solution here is the my error:
it is not getthg the app.css and app.js file correctly
i want to solve my deploy the laravel VueJs proejct onto the cpanel and it creates some issue and i want to solve it well..

If you have run npm run dev, you must find a file in public/hot and Rewrite the proper address / URL in it. For me, http://127.0.0.1:5173 worked.
